# How to properly import a GO packge from Go Multi Module repo?

Tags: go, import, multi-module

Can someone help me with the following:
I have 2 private git repositories private1 and private2.
I need to import a package from repo private1 into private2.
Structure of  repo private1 is as follows :

private1 --

```
       |
       |- actions --
       |              | - go.sum
       |              | - go.mod (github.xyz.com/private1/actions)
       |              | - commons -- (package commons)
       |                             | - commons.go
       |-operations--
       |              | - go.sum
       |              | - go.mod (github.xyz.com/private1/actions)
       |              | - interceptor -- 
       |                             | - interceptor.go
```

I want to import package 'commons' in my other repo private2.
What should be added to the go.mod of repo private 2?
if i use 'github.xyz.com/private1/actions' , i get the following error
go: github.xyz.com/private1/actions@v0.0.0-20211203184031-723259d523a2: unrecognized import path "github.xyz.com/private1/actions'": reading https://github.xyz.com/private1/actions?go-get=1: 404 Not Found

Comment: are your 'git repositories' (modules) locally in your computer or remotely stored (like in github)?

Comment: @Praveen they are stored in github.

Answer (score 0):

Since your modules/packages are in a private git repositories you cannot access them directly, you either have to download the modules locally and use them or publish them so that you (and others) can use.

### How to guides:

- [Developing and publishing modules](https://go.dev/doc/modules/developing)
- [Call your code from another module](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/call-module-code)